# Hibernate - Entity - Database Saving

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and asked to work with a database with tables that has these columns

> Table : tbl_product    //List of Inventory Items 
>   Columns: 
>   
> key_product 
>  
>           key_category 
>           fld_product_name 
>           fld_inventory_qty 
>           fld_unit_price 
>           fld_product_image
>
> Table: tbl_order_detail //Shopping Cart
>   Columns: 
>   key_order_detail 
>   key_order (reference to tbl_order.key_order) 
>   key_product (reference to tbl_product.key_product) 
>   fld_unit_price 
>   fld_quantity
>
> Table tbl_order //Pivot table for Shopping Cart and User -- with total price of shopping cart 
>   Columns: 
>   key_order 
>   key_user 
>   fld_total_amount

And my models (objects) looks like this:

> Model: InventoryItem 
>   Fields: 
>   Product product; 
>   int quantity;
>
> Model: Product 
>   Fields: 
>   int productKey; 
>   String name; 
>   Category category; 
>   BigDecimal unitPrice; 
>   String productImage;
>
> Model: Cart Item 
>   Fields: 
>   Product product; 
>   int quantity;

I am faced with the problem as to how to map the tables with the corresponding models.
I have seen that I can use @Embedded and @Embeddable but due to the restriction that I cannot modify
the database, it seems difficult to do so.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I dont see a reason why you want to split tbl_product into to entity classes: InventoryItem & Product. I would just use one class

Comment: Because if Product will contain the field 'quantity', the field will become useless and won't make sense once the Product is inside 'Shopping Cart Item'

Comment: ooo... thats a bit complex; I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it is possible, that's exactly what is Hibernate used for. Start with Java Persistence API part of Java EE tutorial. This will show you how to map entities to database tables and how to query them.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below.

**Updated:**

Mapping for table: tbl_product

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "key_product")
    private int productKey;

    @Column(name = "fld_product_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "fld_product_name")
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;

    @Column(name = "fld_product_image")
    private String productImage;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="product")
    private InventoryItem inventoryItem;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_product")
public class InventoryItem {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "key_product")
    private int productKey;

    @Column(name = "fld_inventory_qty")
    private int quantity;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Product product;
}
```

Mapping for tbl_order would be

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_order")
public class ShoppingCartItem {

    @Id
    @Column(name="key_order")
    private int keyOrder;

    @Column(name="fld_total_amount")
    private BigDecimal totalAmount;

    //I guess this is a foreign key for User entity. I hope you can map it by yourself 
    @Column(name="key_user")
    private int keyUser;        

@OneToOne(mappedBy="shoppingCartItem")
private ShoppingCartItemDetails shoppingCartDetails;
}
```

Mapping for table tbl_order_detail would be

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_order_detail")
public class ShoppingCartItemDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name="key_order_detail")
    private int keyOrderDetail;

    @Column(name="key_order", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int keyOrder;

    @OneToOne
    //@JoinColumn used to map foreign key with primary key
    @JoinColumn(name="key_order", referencedColumnName="key_order")
    private ShoppingCartItem shoppingCartItem;

    @Column(name="key_product", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int keyProduct;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="key_product", referencedColumnName="key_product")
    private Product product;

    @Column(name="fld_unit_price")
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;

    @Column(name="fld_quantity")
    private int quantity;   
}
```

Comment: The problem that I have seen with this one is that I have another Entity named ShoppingCartItem that will also have reference to Product.

The table for ShoppingCartItem looks something like
key_order, 
key_product (reference to product in the tbl_product), 
fld_unit_price, 
fld_quantity.

Comment: If you could update your question with all the tables you have, I'll try to give the full mapping

Answer (score 0):

also you can use xml mapping, start [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/xml.html)